# Differential equations in Python: Single time step

Tags: python, ode

I would like to be able to do something else in each time step during solving an ODE (using scipy's integrate). Is there a way to do so? Can I somehow write my own time loop and just call a single e.g. Runge-Kutta step by myself? Is there a routine in python or would I have to come up with my own? I think there must be one since odeint etc have to use such a function. So the question is, how do I access them?

So it should looking something along these lines:

```
from scipy.integrate import *
from pylab import *

def deriv(y, t):
    a = -2.0
    b = -0.1
    return array([y[1], a*y[0]+b*y[1]])


time = linspace(0.0, 10.0, 1000)
dt = 10.0/(1000-1)
yinit = array([0.0005, 0.2])

for t in time:
    # doSomething, write into a file or whatever
    y[t] = yinit
    yinit = RungeKutta(deriv, yinit, t, dt, varargs)
```

Comment: Could you provide some  example code of what you are doing/trying ?

Comment: What are you talking about? Python can't solve ODE on its own. You definitely need an external library for that. Are we supposed to guess what you are using? There's no way we can help without that knowledge.

Comment: @freakish Easy. Yes I am talking about additional libraries. The question is, is there a library that already has something I want. Added an example.

Comment: "I would like to be able to do something else in each time step ..." I'm not really sure what's the problem here. Write function/bunch o function each doing "something else" and call them appropriately in your loop.

Comment: @BartoszKP The question is: Is the RungeKutta function which does exactly one Runge-Kutta step already defined? They must be somehow since ode etc. have to use them. Never mind I got the solution now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I now came along with this:

```
from pylab import *
from scipy.integrate import *

def RHS(t, x):
    return -x

min_t = 0.0
max_t = 10.0
num_t = 1e2
grid_t = linspace(min_t, max_t, num_t)
grid_dt = (max_t - min_t)/(num_t - 1)

y = zeros(num_t, dtype=complex)
y[0] = complex(1.0, 0.0)

solver = complex_ode(RHS)
solver.set_initial_value(y[0], grid_t[0]).set_integrator('dopri5')

for idx in range(1, int(num_t)):
    solver.integrate(solver.t + grid_dt)
    y[idx] = solver.y[0]
```

In here I can do whatever I want during the integration.